# What is the command to configure Intellisense in VSCode for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a C++ project, which builds and runs fine on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with VSCode 1.74.3 and gcc 12.1.0. The editor shows a number of squiggly lines, though:

[image]

How can I make Intellisense correctly parse my source file? When I open a command palette and search for "intellisense", I'm getting only these options:

[image]

none of which helps. There was a popup asking about configuring Intellisense for this project, which I disabled, because it prevented the project from building. How can I get "configure Intellisense" option?

Comment: You need to actually go into the settings for the extension and configure it for your system.

Comment: @sweenish Which settings are these? There are: language specific, default, user, workspace and other settings.

Comment: Start reading here to learn about the intellisense settings in `c_cpp_properties.json`: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_cc-configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_cc-configurations)

Comment: As for the squiggles can you give information on what Intellisense believes is wrong with these lines? Do you have `"cppStandard": "c++17",` in that file?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. Intellisense was set to C++17, but C++20 is necessary. I wish it could read the settings from CMakeLists, which explicitly asks for cxx_std_20.

Comment: The cmake extension does that for you.

Comment: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)

Comment: @sweenish I have CMake, CMake Language Support and CMake Tools installed and it didn't help.

Comment: You can try exporting compile_commands.json using cmake and then pointing to that in C++ project settings, that improved things significantly in my case; but truth be told your mileage might vary depending on the exact project settings. Also, give the IDE a while to index you project. Initial config in my case (ca. 10mln LoC C++ project, with some heavy templates here and there) took about 10minutes.

Comment: Did you allow the extension to do its job? It's a prompt, and otherwise automatic. I have not had these issues.

Comment: @sweenish I have not seen a prompt from these extensions. I thought they work in the background only.